# Develop and Debug Python with Remote Server

Tags: python, eclipse

There is a Ubuntu server with Python 3.6 and many other required Python modules installed.

**When using Eclipse for Python development, can I connect Eclipse to the full Python environment installed on the Ubuntu server?**

I don't want to install the whole Python environment in the local PC client.

Thanks.

---

Latest Update:

I have installed the latest Eclipse (2018-12) and PyDev (7.0.3) plugin and Python (3.6.7) on Windows 10. And I have also created a test file called Test.py with the following content:

```
import my_server_module as my; 
print(my.version);
```

It doesn't work at all because the "my_server_module" is not installed on Windows 10, it just installed on the Ubuntun server.

**How can I debug the Test.py with connecting to the python environment on Ubuntu server?**

Comment: Use [remote debugging](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) maybe together with a reverse SSH tunnel if the server is not in the same network.

Comment: @KlausD. I have updated the original question, please help to check, thanks. Can't find remote debugging from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use the virtualenv for python app and load into the eclipse - https://www.michaelpollmeier.com/eclipse-pydev-and-virtualenv

Comment: I have updated the original question with the latest information. Please help to check, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is impossible for remote debugging.
I have installed all the modules in local PC for python development. This is the only way.